# Tangent vector confusion

Tags: multivariable-calculus, tangent-line

I am a little confused, is a tangent vector $T$ a unit vector? I know there is a unit tangent vector defined as

$$T = \frac{r'}{|r'|}.$$

I think the most confusing thing is $T$ is being used for both Tangent vector and unit tangent vector?

Could someone clarify this?

Comment: I have always seen it defined the way you have it. It is a unit vector in the direction of motion. It's possible someone can use $T$ to describe a non-unit tangent vector but usually it is a unit vector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We know the velocity vector $v = \frac{\mathrm dr}{\mathrm dt}$ is tangent to the curve $r(t)$ so it is a tangent vector, but the vector $T$ is its direction vector. Of course, this unit tangent vector (I mean $T$) is a differentiable function of $t$ whenever $v=r'(t)$ is a
differentiable function of $t$.

Comment: Hello! ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: Hello my dear friend. How is everything?

Comment: All is well.  I recognized you by your identicon!  How are you faring?  Thanks for responding, my friend.

Comment: Thanks Amy! Just routine jobs around. Teaching online and cheating online. The first is me and the other are students. Boring job indeed